# function pointer equal to another pointer within the function, why need to add *

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

please take look at Node *newNode(), i dont understand why i must add * for p=x
i made an Node named x(with data & next), and created a new memory space *p by using malloc,
then let p = x, but by i must add * for p=x?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

Node *newNode(int data, Node *next){
    Node x = {data, next};
    Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    *p = x; //i dont understand why an * need to be added here
    return p;
}

showNode(const struct Node *p){
    printf("%d\n", p->data);
}

int main(){
    Node *pHead = NULL;
    for(int i=4; i>=0; i--) {
        pHead = newNode(i,pHead);   
    }    
    printf("%d\n", pHead->next->next->next->data);

    Node* p = pHead;
    while(p != NULL){
        showNode(p);
        p = p-> next;
    }

    p = pHead;
    while(p != NULL){
        Node *pTemp = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(pTemp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is C, why didn't you use the C++-Tag?

Comment: If this is C++, you should not use `malloc` and `free`, but `new` and `delete`. If this is C, you shouldn't tag it C++ and you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: thanks guys~ i fixed the tag~ will be careful next time~

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a pointer. That's just the syntax in c/c++.

If you are using a pointer without the *, you are saying that you want the memory address. When you use the * you instead want the content on that address.

Comment: *p = x is the content of x, p = x is the memory address of x, right?

Comment: I recommend finding a pointer tutorial. I could answer your question, but you're obviously a beginner to pointers and will soon come to next stop. Pointers are tricky and there's lots of pitfalls.

Comment: thanks klutt, i read a lot recent about pointer, heap, and malloc. I was very confuse about pointer when it declares, and when to use asterisk, but as a beginner on this, I thank you for your suggestion, help me a lot, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you just look at the line above the assignment, it says

```
Node *p = ...;
```

So `*p` is a `Node`. And so is `x` from the declaration `Node x = ...;`

If you want to assign one `Node` to another, you use their names `x` and `*p`.

Comment: how is it different from as below
int i = 2;
int *p;
p = i;
printf("%d\n",  p);

Answer (score 0):

*p has two meanings. 1) at the time declaration... Like you write int *p. It means you have declared a pointer to an integer. 2) Not at the time of declaration. *p will now simply mean the data stored in the memory address that p is pointing to.

Comment: so Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); is not at the time of declaration? so i must declare  *p first, then set it equal to x?
like int *p = x?

Comment: @LingLingLing `Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));` declares `p` as a variable of type `Node *` and initializes it to the value on the right hand side of the `=`. It is "at the time of declaration" because it _is_ a declaration of `p`. (It is also a _definition_ of `p` with an _initializer_.)

Comment: @LingLingLing No. You don't have to do it that way.
 Node *p means that p is a pointer to a Node.
 Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); means that the p points to a node whose memory is allocated in heap. This memory will be of the size of a Node but will be empty i.e it has size but not valid data.
Now when you assign  *p(i.e content of memory that p is pointing to) = x you kind of copy the data stored in x to that segment of memory in heap to which p is pointing to.
I suggest you read the fundamentals of dynamic memory allocation and pointers in c/c++ as this will help you in future.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, i took some time in the book(kinda confusing), and asked friends, and of course you guys~ i think i have a clear understanding how how pointer works now~ but still a long way to go for a beginner, thanks again~

Comment: Just for clarification. Node *p does not mean that p is a pointer to a Node. It means that whenever *p is invoked, the content at memory address p will be interpreted as a Node. In most cases you can get away with saying that it's a pointer to a Node, but it's important to understand why that's not 100% correct.